# Getting curl response in Encoded form

Tags: php, curl

I am working on curl to get Zipcode within a radius i wrote curl for this and it is working fine in Shell but when i converted it in PHP i am getting encoded response.  My code is below

php code is

```
$headers = array(
    'Referer:http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Pragma:no-cache',
    'Cache-Control:no-cache',
    'Origin:http://www.freemaptools.com',
    'Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8'        
);


$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.freemaptools.com/ajax/get-all-zip-codes-inside.php?radius=50&lat=36.7017377&lng=-95.87759640000002&rn=8523');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, " __utma=126142042.1539287389.1412828292.1412828292.1412828292.1; __utmb=126142042.1.10.1412828292; __utmc=126142042; __utmz=126142042.1412828292.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1");


$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);


curl_close($curl_handle);


echo '<pre>'; print_r($buffer);
```

Response is some thing like

`‹Å—OoÓ@Å¿J”;aÿÍÎ®ÔVZÚmÕõÛinT¨ZDÃ>=“TY«JØÊ%ÎÁ¿Ì{3og¾ÝüørûãñäèéËè÷Ý÷ŸnÇµÖãÑ×›õñXãDXé•¡çûÏÇã7&AJ?}¼[ÿ:Ÿ†2®èááçýæñ2•Í4]ÆŠ~{\ß¬é}õx´¾ûvûûá~óöñèíËLÃ˜Ê*#2ÓN$"*ÈÌYX4añ~Z0ÿmO020§+¼Ó38ŸÇÕõ¼(â%oKÜ‘Áä2£TÕŽ|C5/§ƒPY½R²šQ½qÝŽ:×¡C@x©B9ËÜÂ[ÈUÎS>Ä!¬µ\`kx©ÔSÂ/vÔ«X-Aò6Ön;)íè(é6³ô„lVUê­-!äi'dXÅµE>7ðÆÏ¦e¦:LcÆ¥‹Ã©ÄA/1Wø.Te}Š¢/R·HÔÜGá¤QŠ!›"ÖÏftêO“Ê½Ñ†¡
jV-M‹NˆWCÃÿC[†V«N;
Mx-´dhDÇãÉ ´6{}:‹EY>Ui«zo"¶Díì()‰3±U¼LUìÍtŒI)ÜñÖJ°­·ƒ1Ï ©¥—ÜT-d›†§©(æåsS›EQ‡½©,.¼Ò[HÛÅè–zÊ!zH1GiJ;ê*šœ|ÚœÅ",·LËÐì_¦gHmÝ2•4-rÉW¦ÃËÔÜPM‡/hmk›è<­æ,…k Ã¬tn“@œç¤u¹Æ"–á*ÌúªjØ˜XtÞØ®‘èsóìý€À$µ‚><ø<=Ë|i?äáN‚æNJÓq… õ7cS‘¦\ÙÃ¼l2;QHk
÷’ö£sè‘uÍ6•ƒbø‰B;‚lyôœŸyWa9[ÔLØƒ–Ë¬°hyïÐDjowÄ*Ðö5ˆ‘Û¤Ùå:Ùº³© %y$ë‹yhÒæ½½„Ež¯Tç®`ØéU^¼À6)ÈZVy-<çz‹RdykZ®«UÏ:S´RJ¯eV¶ }úNˆcÂÒM¡»~9:BÚt½ŽÕ Ýã˜¦žîHºV¢Î»eÙ×BÇvÛÍ=Ð¶8ê^GqžÃn¹*;ò÷‰|û|<ùÃr6…j`

Please help whats wrong with my code,Your Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get same output as in your shell script with something like that :

```
$headers = array(
    'Referer:http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm',
    'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Pragma:no-cache',
    'Cache-Control:no-cache',
    'Origin:http://www.freemaptools.com',
    'Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8'    
);

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.freemaptools.com/ajax/get-all-zip-codes-inside.php?radius=50&lat=36.7017377&lng=-95.87759640000002&rn=8523');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, " __utma=126142042.1539287389.1412828292.1412828292.1412828292.1; __utmb=126142042.1.10.1412828292; __utmc=126142042; __utmz=126142042.1412828292.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1");

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$body = substr($buffer, $header_size);

curl_close($curl_handle);

$body = strtr($body,array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;")); // for displaying html tags
echo($body);
```

In your code, you didn't close your "pre" tag at then end, also,

```
$curl_connection
```

should be

```
$curl_handle
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

and set this to 0, so that you will not get http headers back

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

You told server that you agree to receive gzipped data if possible with `Accept-Encoding:gzip,`

And the result will be HTTP headers of the response (which are absent if CURLOPT_HEADER = 0) + XML

```
<markers><marker zipcode="67333" lat="37.061924" lng="-95.875119" 
city="CANEY" county="MONTGOMERY" state="KS" timezone="6" /> and so on
```

Of course you browser will not show it. Make `echo hmltentities($buffer);` (no need in pre in this case) and you will see it.

Comment: when i am adding this then getting blank page

Comment: Because you are receiving xml.. What do you expect to see in browser? I show output in my answer.

Comment: still getting blank page

Comment: @Vinie enable display of php errors. One error is here `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` Everything works in my code when I run it. This is what I'm running - http://pastebin.com/u2u7UX27

Comment: sorry but not getting any response ):

Comment: @Vinie then you have a bad php version, where cURL compiled, probably, without gzip support. I'm sorry for your setup.